# Fortran90 not writing to standard ouput?

Tags: linux, redirect, fortran90, redirectstandardoutput

I'm writing a UI to go around some numerics code for my research, and I'm having some problems redirecting the output of the code.

The code is written in fortran 90 i believe, and unfortunately, my experience with fortran is fairly minimal. I'm running linux mint 15, and I can't get statements like ./codepath > file to work. These commands work for shell scripts, so I'm confident that the problem lies in the fortran.

Usually the code just prints to the terminal window, so I'm wondering if for some reason PRINT*, doesn't write to standard output? Is there another redirect I can do so I don't have to rewrite the fortran code? If not, what do I change those print statements to so that it will go to standard output?

EDIT: For reference, the bits of the program that I'm talking about look like this:

```
IF (MOD(n,dn) .EQ. 0) THEN
     IF ((DDnew .EQ. 0) .AND. (DDold .EQ. 0)) THEN
        DDerr = 1
     ELSE
        DDerr=ABS(DDnew-DDold)
        RRerr=ABS(MAXVAL(ff(:,:,4))-RRold)
        ERRsum=DDerr+RRerr
        print *, "ERROR =", ERRsum
        CALL output(xx,yy,ff,cw,ycw)
     END IF
  END IF
```

The end goal is to redirect these prints to a text field in the UI program, but I'd like to be able to do that without editing the fortran code too much, thus the need for this to work correctly. :P

Comment: Worked for me on Fedora 18 with gfortran 4.7, could you post some of your code that does not print to file?

Comment: Are you getting errors?  Try ./codepath 1> file 2>&1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible it's printing to standard error which is picked up by the terminal but won't be picked up by a standard redirection. Can you try this:

./codepath > output.txt 2>&1

If that doesn't work can you post some of the Fortran code?

Calling

```
CALL flush(6)
CALL flush(0)
```

After your print statements may also help.

Comment: The flush statements made it work. Can you explain why this is? Again, I'm super new to fortran, and I'm just using this code, it was not written by me, so I'd like to understand it better.

Thanks very much though.

Comment: Part speculation on my part but I believe it just forces your IO to be flushed down those outputs. Previously it wasn't flushing down stdout and stderr.

Comment: Is it possible that the program is failing for other reasons before it finishes execution?  If so, it could easily have strings in the buffer that it never gets around to sending to output, and the flush statements would cure this.  Have seen this happen alot.

Comment: The program does work, and doesn't terminate unexpectedly, but it takes a hell of a long time to run usually (from 8-36 hours generally) but I was expecting it to print in real time.
Is it a feature of fortran that it doesn't do that and only pushes those prints at the end? I guess that makes sense as to why explicitly flushing them down would work. I wasn't waiting for the program to finish, I was just looking at the output file to see if the initial prints were working, and then canceling execution.

Comment: Yes, FORTRAN will definitely buffer printing.  flush just flushes out the buffer.  I think the amount of buffering it does depends on alot of things, space available, details of the FORTRAN implementation, and I don't know what else.

Comment: Note `flush` subroutine is nonstandard. Modern Fortran has `flush` statement (i.e. without `call`), which is preferred in new code and portablehttp://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf111.bg.doc/xlflr/flushstm.htm .

Comment: Vladmir is correct; `flush()` is a Fortran 2003 intrinsic statement; use it instead of `call flush()` Also, check your compiler options. I know in the case of Intel's ifort, output buffering is an option which can be enabled and disabled. The behavior you're seeing is likely compiler-dependent.